# Redirect absolute URL Server 2012 IIS

Tags: web-server, iis-8, seo

We are moving to a new domain and need to redirect users from the original to the new domain.

One of the things I need to do is have it set up so if a user has a saved link such as www.domain.com/questions it redirects to www.newdomain.com/questions.

We have multiple links that need to be redirected for SEO purposes. Apparently you can do this in apache using the htaccess file with the below code,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DomainA.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://DomainB.com/$1 [P]
```

My question is how can I achieve this using the web.config file in IIS or redirection.config?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the issue. you can actually use for for a bunch of stuff

```
<rule name="OriginalDomainRedirection">
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

This if put in the wqeb.config file will redirect any page on domain A to the same page on Domain B. Works great for SEO.